# How to monitor a file if it changes or created with entr?

Tags: linux, automation

I use entr to monitor building a binary and then move it over ssh to another server.
However, sometimes I build clean and the file doesn't exist yet, but entr exits if I do something like this (example):

```
ls "file" | entr pwd
```

How do I forbid entr from exiting and keep waiting for the file to exist or change?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm too late, but anyway here's my solution.

Something similar was in the official github page of entr, I just modified it for my use case.

```
FILE_PATH="file" #1
FILE_JUST_DELETED=false #2
ON_FILE_CHANGED_COMMAND="echo \"File is changed!\"" #3

while sleep 2 #4
  do if [ -f "${FILE_PATH}" ] #5
  then
    if [ $FILE_JUST_DELETED = true ] #6
      then echo "File is just created, executing command" && sh -c "${ON_FILE_CHANGED_COMMAND}" && FILE_JUST_DELETED=false #7
    fi
    echo "Watching the file changes" && find "${FILE_PATH}" | entr -p sh -c "echo \"File is updated. Executing command...\" && ${ON_FILE_CHANGED_COMMAND}" #8
  echo "The file is just deleted." && FILE_JUST_DELETED=true #9
  else echo "File is not present, waiting..." #10
  fi
done
```

I think the code is self-explainatory, but there's some detailed explaination for every line annotated with #n:

1. Path of the file you tracking.
2. Some variable to help us tell then the file is just created.
3. Command to execute then file changes.
4. Sets 2 seconds interval between "is file exist" checks, just to not make millions calls per second. You can set it to whatever interval you need.
5. Check if file exists. If you specified directory in the FILE_PATH you should use -d instead of -f.
6. Without this the ON_FILE_CHANGED_COMMAND would not be executed then file is just created.
7. Block to execute then file is just created.
8. Usual entr command. -p argument is here to prevent executing the command on the first run. If it's not intented you could omit it, but you should also delete the if block described in #6 and the FILE_JUST_DELETED variable.
9. This line executes whenever entr exits, the script assumes that this is because entr detected that the file is deleted. But it could be for any reason including the case when you just pressed Ctrl-C, so beware.
10. File is not found(see line #5), so jump to the line #4 and wait for 2 seconds.

It works like a charm, but as I stated before it have some unintended behaviour then you try to terminate it with Ctrl-C, so to stop this script you need to press Ctrl-C twice between the interval you specified in the line #4. But ideally you should write this into separate shell script and execute it in the background like:

```
./watch-the-file-script &
```

If you really need to run it in the foreground you can replace the line #9 with:

```
if [ ! -f ${FILE_PATH} ]
  then echo "The file is just deleted." && FILE_JUST_DELETED=true
  else break
fi
```